# how to get next and previous posts from wordpress in angular2

Tags: wordpress, angular, angular2-services

how to get next and previous posts from WordPress in angular 2?

I'm using WordPress as backend and angular 2 as front-end. I got all posts from WordPress by using WP rest API (../WP/v2/posts). I want to get next and previous posts json to show in front-end using angular 2.

thanks in advance... please help anyone...

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SingleService } from './singleproject.service';

import { Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-singleproject',
  templateUrl: './singleproject.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./singleproject.component.css'],
  providers: [SingleService]
})
export class SingleprojectComponent implements OnInit {
  public single;
  private params;
  private singleDetails;
  private datas;
  private id;  

  constructor(private singleService :SingleService,
  private _route:ActivatedRoute) { }

  getsingle(){
    this.singleService.getsingle().subscribe( singleDetails => {

      this.singleDetails = singleDetails.find( datas => datas.id === +this.params.id)
    } );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.getsingle();
    this._route.params.subscribe(params=>{
     this.params = params;


 });
  }

}
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  getsingle(){
this.singleService.getsingle().subscribe( singleDetails => {

  this.singleDetails = singleDetails.find( datas => datas.slug ==this.params.id);

      this.array = singleDetails ;

      this.index=this.array.indexOf(this.singleDetails );
      this.nextproject= next[this.index+1];
      this.previousproject= next[this.index-1]

    } );

  }
```

i get the previous and next posts by using indexof. it working for me